# Failed to download repository information from 18.04

Tags: package-management, updates, repository

I am running 18.04LTS and am trying to get my system to download the 20.04 release.  Running update-manager with no arguments is failing.  It starts downloading the repository information, gets 90% done, then aborts with "Failed to download repository information.  Check your internet connectiion."

I am able to ping, traceroute and http to www.ubuntu.com and archive.ubuntu.com with no problems.  My internet connection is just fine for other destinations.

Now "apt update" is not working.

```
sudo apt update
[sudo] password for jms: 
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]      
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu bionic Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'allow-insecure=yes/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'allow-insecure=yes' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'allow-insecure=yes/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'allow-insecure=yes' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'allow-insecure=yes/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'allow-insecure=yes' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'allow-insecure=yes/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'allow-insecure=yes' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'allow-insecure=yes/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'allow-insecure=yes' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'allow-insecure=yes/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'allow-insecure=yes' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'allow-insecure=yes/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'allow-insecure=yes' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'allow-insecure=yes/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'allow-insecure=yes' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) and [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017)

Comment: I ended up downloading  the ISO and  installing from flash.  The disadvantage is that I have to "apt install" all the fiddly bits again.

Comment: Most of the latter can be scripted to run in the background after the installation is finished.